# toggle not closing when click a link jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a one page website. This piece of code opens a menu which contain a list of links. 
What I'm trying to do is that when the user click on one of the links inside the "dropmenu" closes the dropmenu and take the user to the link.

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/menu.png" width="22" height="23" alt="Logo" style="margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;" id="menudiv"></a>
<div id="dropMenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#index2">Contact Us</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).next("div").stop('true','true').slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: what is happening  currently ,what is problem?

Comment: What I'm trygin to do is to close the toggle when I click on one of the link inside the 'div' because when I click back on the browers the menu is still open

Comment: Can you please make a jsfiddle?

Comment: hello , link which is in ul  li , where it will go ,on other page or same page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/programmer101/8YqKc/) what you want? Hope it helps.

I added this code

```
 $("li").click(function() {
        $("#dropMenu").hide("slow");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LuEGd/) is what are you trying to do?

Added `id` to the dropdownmenu so it wouldn't confuse with the other `<a>` tags.

Comment: is something like this, but my problem is how can close the menu when I click on one of the links inside the 'dropmenu' id

Answer (score 0):

Use preventDefault:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();    
$(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).next("div").stop('true','true').slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```